# How to log pattern work time during X-country?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I am working on my IFR part 61 and must have 50 hours of X-country as PIC.

1. Lets say my instructor and I fly to an airport that is **55 miles** from my take off airport - it takes us **0.8 hours** from take off to land.
2. Then, on our way back, we do pattern work at another airport - **0.4 hours** to fly and **0.7 hours** for pattern work.
3. Then, final leg of flying - **0.3 hours**.

Total flight time - 0.8 + 0.4 + 0.7 + 0.3 = **2.2 hours**

What is the best and legal way to log this **1.5 hours** of X-country, in my log book? If I could, I would like to take advantage of the **0.3 + 0.4 hours** during my return flight as X-country time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FAA: May I log as cross-country a flight with two or more short legs?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23459/faa-may-i-log-as-cross-country-a-flight-with-two-or-more-short-legs) And [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/55825/62) might be relevant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log it all as XC. This is quite common. XC is all flight time to an airport more than 50 NM away from origin, even if you don't spend it flying in a straight line.